# Know algorithms to change the colour of a product

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

My question might be off topic, but I didn't a better forum to ask.

I need to change the color of a product on an eCommerce website. We have many styles and many colours, so taking a picture of every combination is out of question (about 100 styles and colours, which will result in 10,000 pictures. We just don't have time to take that many pictures or process them manually). However, I could take a picture of every product and and a picture of one style in every colours and then make a program which generate all the missing pictures. I was thinking using something like OpenCV (and probably python) which provide lots classic computer vision algorithm off the shelf, to do so. Before doing it, I'm sure this is a classic image processin problem. Does it have a name or is there any algorithm or resources on the topic ?

In other world, there are apps and program which allows you to change the colour of our dress or clothes. Does any body knows how it works or have usefull resources related to this problem ?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88427/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48924606/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Moreover, on CS.SE folks already gave you feedback and suggested some possible approaches (before you posted here).  Why didn't you mention those?  That seems impolite -- it may lead people to repeat information you've already received, without realizing it.

Comment: well, feed back I got from CS SE what that the question was off-topic so I decide to try somewhere else. I looked at the tags finding that there is 5700 follower of image-processing on SE vs 26 on CS. I decided that SE was probably better indeed.

Comment: @mb14, ok, in the future, if you're going to re-post the question elsewhere, please delete the original copy so people know not to continue trying to respond there.  You might notice that some folks on CS.SE were trying to help you improve the question so it would be on-topic.  Also, again, when you get some feedback and suggestions and don't mention that here in your question and don't explain why you have rejected that suggestion, you risk wasting people's time here (if they re-explain the same idea without realizing you've already heard it and didn't find it useful), which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You separate intesity from colour information. Then you change the colour information and merge both back together.

This will give you an image with changed colours but maintained brightness. So shadows, highlights and so on stay untouched.

You have to convert your RGB touples to a colour space that has separate coordinates for intensity and colour.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space as one example

Of course you may restrict these operations to your "product" so anything else remains unchanged.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to actually "find" the product, considering I have a picture of another one in a similar colour ?

Comment: @mb14 not sure what you mean with find that product. you should create those template images specifically for that recolouring process. the usual approach is to put the product in front of  a special background that allows easy segmentation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key